# Learning ArcGIS Spatial Analyst?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, references

Does anyone know of some resources to learn more about Spatial Analyst and raster analysis?

I'd like to sharpen up for some job stuff, but I'd like to find some resources to practice on.

Answer (score 4):

There is an [ArcGIS Spatial Analyst tutorial](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00nt00000002000000) available which I suggest would make an excellent starting point. The tutorial scenario is:

> The town of Stowe, Vermont, USA, has experienced a substantial
> increase in population. Demographic data suggests this increase has
> occurred because of families with children moving to the region,
> taking advantage of the many recreational facilities located nearby.
> It has been decided that a new school must be built to take the strain
> off the existing schools, and as a town planner, you have been
> assigned the task of finding the potential site.
>
> This tutorial will
> show you how to use many of the available tools and will give you a
> solid basis from which you can start to think about how to solve your
> own specific spatial problems.